# Template parameters are arranged in the wrong order. Is it correct?

Tags: c++, templates

I expect the following output in the following program: 2 1.2. But the list of template parameters is reversed (as I understand). Should it be like that?

```
void print_id(int i, double d) noexcept {
    std::cout << i << ' ' << d << std::endl;
}
template <typename G>
int mycode(G item, std::string & p) noexcept {
    p.append((const char*)&item, sizeof(G));
    return 1;
}

template<typename G>
const char* iterate(const char* &p) noexcept {
//  std::cout << (typeid(G)).name() << " "; It gets know that the first type is 'double', the next is 'int'
    const char* ans = p;
    p += sizeof(G);
    return ans;
}

template<typename ...T>
std::function<void(const char*)> state_f(void(*func)(T...)) {
    return [func](const char* p) {
        func(*(const T*)(iterate<T>(p))...);
    };
}

template<typename ...T>
std::string encode(T... tpl) noexcept {
    std::string s;
    int crutch[] = { mycode<T>(tpl, s)... };
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    auto f = state_f(print_id);
    f(encode(2, 1.2).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

I can reverse the parameters but I don't think it is correct.

Comment: This doesn't compile. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: The only output is in `print_id` and will always print an integer first, then a double. How are you expecting it to output a floating point first?

Comment: What did You notice during debug stepping through that was not as expected?

Comment: @eukaryota I changed the example and did not notice. I expect the same order as in the 'encode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key lines in the shown code:

```
 int crutch[] = { mycode<T>(tpl, s)... };
```

The parameter pack will expand, basically, to:

```
 int crutch[] = { mycode<double>(1.3, s), mycode<int>(2, s) };
```

The implementation of `mycode`, to make a long story short, appends its argument to a buffer.

The issue here is that in this instance, C++ does not have a guaranteed evaluation order. Either function call may get executed first, and it may very well be different each time you run the same program. You are not guaranteed a left-to-right evaluation order, in this context. Either argument may end up being appended to the buffer, first.